# React native - How to set the container or text input dynamically, which is responsive for all devices

Tags: reactjs, css, react-native, mobile

I am using react-native. I need to set the input container or the text input box which needs to be  responsive for all devices. How to write the css style to calculate the width and height dynamically.

Refer screenshot for input box with width 375 and height 27 developed in iPhone 7 plus.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

React Native takes a style prop that can contain a lot of very CSS-like attributes. Width, for example, is pretty much like what you would find in the MDN docs for CSS width attribute. You can achieve responsiveness with either a percent-based width:

`style = {{ width: '100%' }}`

...or using flexbox. More information about that below.

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/height-and-width

Answer (score 0):

There are many tricks to do this:

**1 - Using Percentage :**

```
<View
  style={{
    width: '80%',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center', 
  }}
>
  <TextInput
    style={{
      width: '100%',
      height: 27,
    }}
  />
</View>
```

the idea here is to put the `TextInput` (which has a width of 100% and a fixed height = 27) inside a `View` (the container), then give a width to the text input container using percentage (for exemple 90% or 80% ...)

For **best practices**, in case of `TextInput` try always to use percentage for *width* and fixed value for *height*

**2 - Using Dimensions**

```
<View
  style={{
    width: Dimensions.get('window').width,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center', 
  }}
>
  <TextInput
    style={{
      width: '100%',
      height: 27,
    }}
  />
</View>
```

here we have calculated the width of the screen and set it to the width of the text input container

Of course, you have to import Dimensions from react-native

```
import { Dimensions } from 'react-native'
```

But for me, I prefer using the first solution